# Loading a RDF/XML File using owl api

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I'm trying to open a rdf/xml file using the OWL API. The file is accessible from:

http://www.dmi.unict.it/~longo/comunect/comunect.owl

If I download the file and  try to open it with the loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(File file)  of OWLOntologyManager class. I obtain the following error:

```
    org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.UnparsableOntologyException: Problem parsing file:/C:/myfile.owl
    Could not parse ontology.  Either a suitable parser could not be found, or parsing failed.  See parser logs below for explanation.
    The following parsers were tried:
    1) RDFXMLParser
    2) OWLXMLParser
    3) OWLFunctionalSyntaxOWLParser
    4) TurtleOntologyParser
    5) KRSS2OWLParser
    6) ManchesterOWLSyntaxOntologyParser
    7) OBOFormatOWLAPIParser
    8) OWLOBO12Parser
Parser: RDFXMLParser
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/myfile.owl; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; the content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Now, since I can open the file with Protege, why I can't parse the ontology with the owl api library ?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you view any specific errors from the RDFXMLParser?

Comment: Hello, I've edited the post with the error.

Comment: This is expected to work, especially because Protege 4.x uses OWL API to manage ontologies, so it's literally the same code being used. A content not allowed in prolog error usually means that the file contains invalid characters right at its beginning, but of course this cannot be verified here. Can you share the actual file somehow? You can email it to the OWL API mailing list or open an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues

Comment: Topic updated. The problem arises only if I download the file.

Comment: If you want help, you should show us the java source code, ideally an  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).